# Set TabBar Item Disabled Color

Tags: ios, swift, tabbar

My Current tabBar :

[image]

Expected tabbar with disabled tabs(ignore the language its for sample purpose):

[image]

I am able to disable items from my first tab bar image by using this :

```
        self.isEnabled = false
```

For Not loggedin users i disabled these items but i want to change their color to something dull. How to do that.

Note : I am not asking for changing color in unselected state. I am asking only for the disabled state.

Comment: `if let items = tabBarController?.tabBar.items {
        items.forEach { $0.isEnabled = false }
}` you can try that?

Answer (score 0):

Add your following tab bar images as white.

[image]

**Like**

[image]

And in you `MainStoryboard` select your Main TabBarController, then change the `image tint` to `Red` **(whatever color you need to show the image color)**

[image]

Then you can see that the unselected TabBar Items color looks disabled.

Answer (score 0):

To make look like disabled tabbar item.

```
if  let arrayOfTabBarItems = tabBarViewController.tabBar.items as! AnyObject as? NSArray,tabBarItem = arrayOfTabBarItems[2] as? UITabBarItem {
            tabBarItem.enabled = false
        }
```